# Parsing XML with Xpath on logstash

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, logstash

I'm new to XML parsing,  I'm trying to ingest folder with multiple file that have multiple XML logs/ I'm using filebeat to push the logs into logstash.

here is my LOGSTASH conf :

```
  input {
  beats {
     port => 5044
   }
 }
 filter{
   xml{
    target => "doc"
    store_xml => false
    source => "message"
    xpath =>
    ["/E2ETraceEvent/System/EventID/@EventID", "event_id",
     "/E2ETraceEvent/System/Type/@Type", "type",
     "/E2ETraceEvent/System/SubType/@SubType", "name",
     "/E2ETraceEvent/System/Level/@Level", "level",
     "/E2ETraceEvent/System/TimeCreated/@TimeCreated", "time"]
 }
 }
 output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "100.101.15.181:9200"
     manage_template => false
     index => "t11-%{+YYYY.MM}"
   }
 }
```

here is example of one row XML log:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-30T14:10:24.9708868Z" /><Source Name="All Events" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5840" ThreadID="6" /><Channel/><Computer>T-XXXX</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem>Timestamp: 4/30/2018 10:10:24 AM&#xD;&#xA;Message: T-XXX &#xD;&#xA;Method: XXX.Common.Config.Config:System.Object GetConfigFromDB(System.String, System.String, System.String) &#xD;&#xA;XXXX.Common.Config.Config:GetConfigFromDB: Done reading key:ClientAccountBaseURL for ApplicatioName:XXXX.DataLayer.AppDomainKey. value:https://test.XXXX.com/account&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Category: Information&#xD;&#xA;Priority: 8&#xD;&#xA;EventId: 0&#xD;&#xA;Severity: Information&#xD;&#xA;Title:T-XXXX &#xD;&#xA;Method: XXXX.Common.Config.Config:System.Object GetConfigFromDB(System.String, System.String, System.String) &#xD;&#xA;XXXX.Common.Config.Config:GetConfigFromDB: Done reading key:ClientAccountBaseURL for ApplicatioName:XXXX.DataLayer.AppDomainKey. value:https://test.XXXX.com/account&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Machine: T-XXXX&#xD;&#xA;App Domain: /YY/GGGG/1/ROOT/UnlistedUpgrade-1-131695710240192502&#xD;&#xA;ProcessId: 5840&#xD;&#xA;Process Name: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe&#xD;&#xA;Thread Name: &#xD;&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:4760&#xD;&#xA;Extended Properties: </DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

in my conf I'm tryig to parse only couple of columns because of the complexity
of log, I need to parse all the log data.

I'm on it couple of day and i don't get any errors on logstash log or filebeat
but no data inserted into ELASTIC.

can someone help me to understand how to work it out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   xml{
    target => "doc"
    store_xml => false
    source => "message"
    xpath =>
    ["//EventID/text()", "event_id",
     "//Type/text()", "type",
     "//SubType/text()", "name",
     "//Level/text()", "level",
     "//TimeCreated/@SystemTime", "time"]
 }
```